# Jest (enzyme) find not working but element is exist in html

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I would like to find the button in my component and simulate a click.

I have code:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
 
console.log(wrapper.html()); // <div><button class="myButton">Save</button><button variant="light" class="myButton">Close</button></div>

console.log(wrapper.contains('button')); // false 
console.log(wrapper.filter('button')); // false
```

I don't understand what is wrong, button exist - you can see it in `wrapper.html()`

Same for demo example:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
  <div>
    <button>xx</button>
  </div>,
);

console.log(wrapper.html()); //  <div><button>xx</button></div>

console.log(wrapper.contains('button')); // false
console.log(wrapper.filter('button')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

[.contains(nodeOrNodes) => Boolean](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/contains.html) method accepts `ReactElement|Array<ReactElement>` as its parameter, NOT a [selector](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html).

[.filter(selector) => ShallowWrapper](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/filter.html) method accept a `selector` as its parameter.

> Returns a new wrapper with only the nodes of the current wrapper that match the provided selector.

For more unit testings, see [filter](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/6f60a00ef95834516603352206b7d6b88b796f54/packages/enzyme-test-suite/test/shared/methods/filter.jsx)

E.g.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('64240490', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <div>
        <button className="foo">xx</button>
        <span className="foo">foo</span>
      </div>,
    );
    expect(wrapper.contains(<button className="foo">xx</button>)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find('.foo').filter('button')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64240490/index.test.tsx (9.234s)
  64240490
    ✓ should pass (11ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.209s
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Ag-Grid dynamically inserts HTML into the `AgGridReact` component due to DOM virtualization.

You have several options here, depending on the testing strategy, which you may eventually mix-and-match.

### Testing using JSDOM

If you want to keep testing with JSDOM, you may either disable DOM virtualization, at the expense of performance, or rather call `wrapper.render().find()` instead of `wrapper.find()`.

The limitation here is that the Enzyme [render()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/render.html) method returns a `CheerioWrapper` (see [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) project) rather than a `ReactWrapper`. That means the subsequent `find()` method has a different semantic with respect to the most common [find()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) one. The former can only be used to query statically rendered DOM elements, **which you cannot interact with**, such as attempting to programmatically call event handlers (check this [issue](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1233) in the `enzymejs` GitHub repository).

### Testing using Ag-Grid's Grid API

Alternatively, whenever it's feasible and depending on what you're trying to achieve with your test, you may directly interact with Ag-Grid using its Grid API.

The advantage is that this approach is perfectly compatible with the DOM virtualization feature of Ag-Grid, and may be used to perform any kind of interaction with the `AgGridReact` component.

---

##### References

- https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/testing/
- https://blog.ag-grid.com/testing-ag-grid-react-jest-enzyme/